# BusinessObjects | Webi Reports| Help Required on data summary

Tags: report, summary, business-objects

I need help on SAP BusinessObjects – Web Intelligence tool for Reports.

Is there any way we can summarize (Sum of a column, Total Number rows in a column etc.) the data on one Report tab in other tab of the report?
Has anyone implemented this in any project?

Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not directly as each block is unique to the tab. You could expose your block as a service and use that in the other tabs or even in other reports. i am assuming this is XI.

To publish a block right click on the block and you should be able to see a publish block option. Follow the wizard through.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the contexts (both input or output, according to your need)  for this job.